# UWP xaml textbox focus

Tags: xaml

When I start typing into my TextBox (it is the only visual element on my page) then it always hasfocus (cursor is blinking in the TextBox) even when I click outside the TextBox or if I hit enter. The consequence is that TextBox's value, which is binded to a property in code behind, doesn't update the property in code behind.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the Property UpdateSourceTrigger in your Binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
```

The setter gets now called every time the Text changes...

Comment: To be honest, I don't want my model to be updated everytime user hits a key when typing in the TextBox. I'd rather want the model to be updated just when user clicks away from the TextBox or when he hits enter. And I also want the TextBox to loose focus.

Comment: You could programmatically catch the Click or Enter Event and set the focus to another control (e.g. a hidden textbox)

Comment: Hmm, that will be messy... Hope there is some built in behaviour in TextBox which could do that.